# Cannot implement SURF in Android using JavaCV

Tags: android, javacv, surf

I am trying to develop a simple Android app that will get the current frame from the camera on the phone using `PreviewCallback`. Then perform SURF feature detection and extraction using the `ObjectFinder` provided in the JavaCV project. However I keep getting an Exception. The same program works on my PC.

This is probably due to SURF being a patented algorithm and this is causing issues.

Thus can somebody provide me an alternative for this in JavaCV. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct. SURF/SIFT being a patented one, it has been removed from the latest opencv SDK. As an alternative you can try to use the [androidobjectrecognition](https://code.google.com/p/androidobjectrecognition/)  methods used in the same. You can checkout its source from: https://code.google.com/p/androidobjectrecognition/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

I tried use ObjectFinder too. But after unsuccessful attempts I found [this code](https://javacv.googlecode.com/git-history/02385ce192fb82f1668386e55ff71ed8d6f88ae3/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/ObjectFinder.java). After little corrective it work for me in android.

**Basil** is right, but there are many new features to find images [(freak, orb, brisk...)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html).